# How do I list which groups a user is in for my MediaWiki extension?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm writing an extension that will allow me to add the magic words: `CURRENTUSER`, `CURRENTUSERREALNAME`, `CURRENTUSERLANGABBR`, and I wanted `CURRENTUSERGROUPS`.
That section of my code is currently:

```
function wfGetCustomVariable(&$parser,&$cache,&$index,&$ret) {
    switch ($index) {
        case MAG_CURRENTUSER:
            $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
            $ret = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->mName;
            break;
        case MAG_CURRENTUSERREALNAME:
            $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
            $ret = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->mRealName;
            break;
        case MAG_CURRENTUSERLANGABBR
            $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
            $ret = $GLOBALS['wgLang']->getCode();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I can't seem to find the $GLOBAL for the array of groups the user is in anywhere in the MediaWiki documentation.  I've looked in [Manual:Configuration_settings](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfiguration_settings), [Manual:LocalSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aLocalSettings.php), [Manual:CommonSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCommonSettings.php), [Manual:$wgGroupPermissions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgGroupPermissions), and [Help:User_rights](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aUser_rights).  In none of them do I see any explanation of how to get a simple (comma/semi-colon/etc..) delimited list of the current user's groups.  Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/User.php?view=markup#l2300:

```
$GLOBALS['wgUser']->getGroups()
```

...which of course will return an array, not delimiter-separated string.

Comment: After flipping through the code at your link, it also doesn't include implicit groups.. Would: `$ret = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->mEffectiveGroups;` work?

Comment: No. Although it may be a implicitly public variable, never use that way (I'm not a PHP MediaWiki developer, but I don't like their style). There should always be a getter function - in here it is on line 2318.

Comment: This is my first attempt into writing in PHP, and I'm not enrolled in any PHP classes until Fall `12.  That being said, can you point me to a tutorial on how to turn the array I receive into a comma-delimited list?

Comment: You are saying that: `$GLOBALS['wgUser']->getName();` - `$GLOBALS['wgUser']->getRealName();` - `$GLOBALS['wgLang']->getCode();` - `$GLOBALS['wgUser']->getEffectiveGroups();` are superior?

Comment: Yes, definitely. They for example handle caching etc., so always try to use getters. I'm also not sure whether $wgUser should be acessed by $GLOBALS, that looks odd to me - yet again, I'm not a PHP developer.

Comment: @turning array into a list: There's [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). When I explored PHP, I had the [function reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) never more than two clicks away :-)

Comment: Based on that, the correct code would be: `$array = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->getEffectiveGroups();` and then `$ret = implode(",", $array);` -- Correct?

Comment: Ah, found it. The correct way seems to be the [getUser() method of a ContextSource](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classContextSource.html#a4a84d5f0344e114f266fef48c6558999), e.g. Outputpage. The rest looks fine.

Comment: I need this to be compatible with MW 1.17.1 (my host wiki), and that seems to only apply to MW 1.18+.  :(

Comment: Please see the next stage question to this one, "[How do I find out how many edits a user has for my mediawiki extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219229/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-edits-a-user-has-for-my-mediawiki-extension)".  Next phase is to add user edit counters..