# How do I find out how many edits a user has for my MediaWiki extension?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm writing an extension that will allow me to add the magic words: `CURRENTUSER`, `CURRENTUSERREALNAME`, `CURRENTUSERLANGABBR`, `CURRENTUSERGROUPS`, and now I want to add `CURRENTUSEREDITCOUNT` and `CURRENTUSEREDITCOUNTALL`.

That section of my code is currently:

```
function wfGetCustomVariable(&$parser,&$cache,&$index,&$ret) {
switch ($index) {
    case MAG_CURRENTUSER:
        $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
        $ret = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->getName();
        break; 
    case MAG_CURRENTUSERREALNAME:
        $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
        $ret = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->getRealName();
        break;
    case MAG_CURRENTUSERLANGABBR
        $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
        $ret = $GLOBALS['wgLang']->getCode();
        break;
    case MAG_CURRENTUSERGROUPS
        $parser->disableCache(); # Mark this content as uncacheable
        $array = $GLOBALS['wgUser']->getEffectiveGroups();
        $ret = implode(",", $array);
        break;
}
return true;
}
```

However, I can't seem to find the $GLOBAL for the edit counts.  I've done some research based on other extensions that use different edit counts for different reasons and have found:

For [CURRENTUSEREDITCOUNT](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/Contributionseditcount/Contributionseditcount.php?view=markup#l27):

```
function wfContributionseditcount( $uid ) {
if ( $uid != 0 ) {
        global $wgOut, $wgLang;
        $wgOut->addWikiText( wfMsgExt( 'contributionseditcount', array( 'parsemag' ),
        $wgLang->formatNum( User::edits( $uid ) ),
        User::whoIs( $uid ) ) );
    }
    return true;
}
```

and for [CURRENTUSEREDITCOUNTALL](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/CountEdits/CountEdits.page.php?view=markup#l21):

```
public function execute( $params ) {
    global $wgOut, $wgUser;
    $skin = $wgUser->getSkin();
    $this->setHeaders();
    $this->loadRequest( $params );
    $wgOut->addHTML( $this->makeForm() );
    if( $this->target ) {
        if( User::isIP( $this->target ) ) {
            $this->showResults( $this->countEditsReal( 0, $this->target ) );
        } else {
            $id = User::idFromName( $this->target );
            if( $id ) {
                $this->showResults( $this->countEditsReal( $id, false ), $id );
            } else {
                $wgOut->addHTML( '<p>' . wfMsgHtml( 'countedits-nosuchuser', htmlspecialchars( $this->target ) ) . '</p>' );
            }
        }
    }
    $this->showTopTen( $wgOut );
    return true;
}
```

I have tried to learn PHP on my own in the past, and have struggled with it.  I'm signed up for a PHP class at my local community college, but I do not start until Fall `12.  Am I looking in the right place, or is there a simpler place to find the user's edit counts? Maybe as part of [/trunk/phase3/includes/User.php](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/User.php?view=markup) someplace?  I should mention this needs to run on a wiki running MW 1.17.1, so [classUser](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classUser.html) would not work where-as it is MW 1.18+.

Comment: Please press Ctrl+F at User.php, then insert "editcount".

Comment: Okay, I see `$GLOBALS['wgUser']->getEditCount()` [getEditCount()](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/User.php?view=markup#l2389) for my `CURRENTUSEREDITCOUNT`, but what about the edit count including deleted articles for `CURRENTUSEREDITCOUNTALL`?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such counter, i.e. you will need to query the database (and eventually extend User.php). Have you tried [asking](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication) at [mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Support_desk)?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to change the definition of edit count, perhaps you should directly change the code where it reduces the user's editcount after a page is deleted.